# Failing in_category or has_category in the_content_feed

Tags: categories, rss

I'm attempting to test post category within RSS output, however both in_category() or has_category() functions will fail. Testing category "manually" will work. What am I missing?

```
    add_filter( "the_content_feed", "RSS_my_filter" );

    function RSS_my_filter($content){
    global $post;
    if (has_category('Class Blog', $post-ID)){
        // FAILS!!!!  
        $content = '***************';
    }
    $categories_list = get_the_category( $post->ID );
    foreach ($categories_list as $category) {
         if($category->name == 'Class Blog'){
            // WORKS 
            $content = '***************';
        }
    }
    return $content;
    }
```

Comment: There's a typo in your code. You should use `$post->ID` instead of `$post-ID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$post-ID` is not the same as `$post->ID`. You’re using the former for `has_category()`, but the latter for `get_the_category()`. `$post->ID` is correct.